# Simple way to store extra user information in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, registration

Playing around for the first time with ASP.NET MVC 3 and really struggling to do what should be extremely simple.

I'm having a user register using the built-in membership functionality, but I want to store their first name and last name as well, which are not properties that are provided by default.

I cannot figure out how to add these properties to the MembershipUser class (if that's even the right class, it's hard to really figure out what's going on here). I also tried creating a new "UserDetails" model, but couldn't figure out how to link that to the regular user table using the UserID as a foreign key.

What is the correct approach to storing extra user information in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application using a Code First approach? I must be doing something wrong here because this has to be brain dead simple. I'm seeing stuff about Custom Profile Providers that just seems so excessive for such basic functionality.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the default Membership schema?

Comment: Id bet big that yes. I've found best way to deal with standard .Net Membership is to expand the actual user table directly or with a join table / view and consume it into entity model.

Comment: Use simplemembershipprovider from mvc4 (technically from the webmatrix libraries)

Comment: Ps in addition Brock Allen open sourced his providers too

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those properties in the `RegisterModel` as below:

```
 public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
       //Put annotatons as needed
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
    }
```

After this , you will need to put those details in the database using the `Register` method in `AccountController`. This can be managed by taking the `UserId` from `Membership` and putting the extra details in a completely different table against this `UserId`in database.This table can be as below:

```
public class ExtendedUser
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So your `Register` method, that is annoted with `[HttpPost]` changes to the following to store the data in above table.

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
           //Get UserId for registered user
            var UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey;
            ExtendedUser extrainfo = new ExtendedUser();
            extrainfo.UserId = UserId;
            extrainfo.FirstName= model.FirstName;
            extrainfo.LastName= model.LastName;
            //Add this info to database
            db.ExtendedUsers.Add(extrainfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Offcourse, you will need to add this new table the class inherited from `DbContext` class
as below:

```
 public class YourContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ExtendedUser> ExtendedUsers{ get; set; }
    }
```

hussh...and you are done.

**Edit :**

Microsoft has done this in a different way at [How to: Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx), but they are missing something in there.But you can have a look at it.

Comment: Hey thanks, this looks like the approach I was trying before but with some things fixed that will hopefully help me out. One thing I don't have is this "db" variable that is providing the SaveChanges() method and stuff, where is that coming from? Thanks.

Comment: Also, is this seriously the best way to get the UserID? var UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey; I don't doubt it, but man what a horrifying piece of code to get something so simple. I come from PHP MVC frameworks where this sort of thing is so trivial so this has been a pretty excruciating exercise...

Comment: @AW. That `db` is nothing but the context name. You must go through entioty framework details before doing this. And yes, I have used chaining for getting the `userid` like jquery, you can off course simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would not use the default `Membership` tools, as the database schema consists almost entirely of BLOB fields, and the default providers assume you want to use their embedded ADO logic. Since you mentioned Code First, I assume you are (or want to be) using Entity Framework. It's not terribly hard to write a custom `Membership` provider that can leverage EF (or any other data-access tool, for that matter).

If you need direction, you can find the implementations I use for both the `Membership` and `Role` providers of my personal site here: https://github.com/tiesont/Monkey.CMS/tree/master/Monkey.Web/Core/Providers - and yes, custom providers are overkill, since you can see by my implementations that most of the abstract base class methods don't need to be implemented to get a working provider.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an MVC-specific answer, but ASP.Net Membership providers are designed for straightforward authorization scenarios and not attaching additional information. [Per the MSDN docs on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.98%29.aspx): "Membership can also be integrated with user profile properties to provide application-specific customization that can be tailored to individual users."

You'll want to [create a profile schema that contains properties for the first and last name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), maybe something like this:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
     <add name="FirstName" type="System.String" />
     <add name="LastName" type="System.String" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

and then you can reference their profile details [from the HTTP context User property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewfkf772%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Also see [Walkthrough: Maintaining Web Site User Information with Profile Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Good luck!